# Open all Excel files in a folder and save using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

There are many small excels tables references a main table, but users don't have permission for for the main table. The owner is running the script so the tables are updated then users see the fresh data. Everyone only sees their own table (GDPR data).

I can't set permissions on the main table, password to the main table is not a solution, it asks users when updating data.

I found no other solution, so i want to use a script.

I want to open all Excel files (.xlsx) from one folder and save it using PowerShell.

The following solution works fine to a file:

```
$dir="C:\Temp\IPK_XY.xlsx"
$excl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$wrkb=$excl.Workbooks.Open($dir)
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$wrkb.Save()
$wrkb.Close()
$excl.Quit()
```

But how can all files be opened and saved in a similar way?

Thank you (and sorry for my English)!

Regards,
T

Comment: To clarify, you want to run the same script for all the files in one same folder?

Comment: I would run this script once a month for the same folder (the data in the main table is changed once a month). There are currently 27 files in the folder, each named IPK_username.xlsx. I want to run one script that opens and saves all the tables.

Comment: Then use a loop to open them. Hint use [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to iterate through the 'IPK_*.xlsx' files and below the definition of the $excel object, have the workbook `$wrkb` open and save them in a loop. Then, after that quit and clode Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you need a loop to open and save the xlsx files like this:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\where\the\files\are' -Filter 'IPK_*.xlsx' -File
$excl     = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $false

foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
    $wrkb.Save()   # or use just $wrkb.Close($true) to save and close
    $wrkb.Close()
}
# now quit excel and clean-up the used COM objects
$excl.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wrkb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excl)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: No error message but nothing happened, the tables have not been updated / the modification date hasn't changed. :(

Comment: It works! I just misspelled a character. Thank you!

Comment: @Alphabet Thanks for the nice feedback! I just took out a comment line that was from an earlier code.

Comment: @Alphabet Could you please tell me why you decided to un-accept my answer?

Comment: may have been a misclick, not intentional, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all the files in the folder, and then run a loop against each item. The loop will repeat all the actions you want to perform

```
# this is the path of the folder with all your files
# get all the files in this folder
$folderPath = "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\gnl pbi\asdasd"    
$fileList = Get-ChildItem $folderPath

$excl = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE

# this is the loop with your desired actions
foreach ($fileName in $fileList)
{
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $fileName

    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
    $wrkb.Save()
    $wrkb.Close()
}

$excl.Quit()
```

Comment: Returned many error messages but nothing happened, the tables have not been updated / the modification date hasn't changed.
.android / .atom etc not found, COM-object error

Comment: Sorry I just realized I had a wrong variable name, which I've updated in my answer